# vba userforms carriage return behavior

Tags: vba, excel, newline, carriage-return, userform

In a textbox of a userform in VBA, I would like to enable the feature where the user can add a new line in the textbox by pressing the "Enter" key on the keyboard. However, I had trouble finding a UI option in the UI editor to achieve this. Is this even allowed in VBA userforms? Thanks in advance for the advices and answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set textbox's MultiLine property to True and EnterKeyBehavior to True.

Comment: Note: Someone might want to consider TabKeyBehaviour = true in case you want to allow entering [TAB] as well instead of hopping to the next control. Not related to the question, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried incorporating the rich text control for text? Not sure how well it works with VBA, but in VB6 this is what I would use.